# jQuery Animation with Time Issue

Tags: jquery

How do I get this http://cnanney.com/journal/demo/apple-counter/countdown.php to countdown to 10AM everyday and then restart. It's for a daily deadline.

I already have a script that does this but in far more basic form, however I want the transition effect achieved here (found this link on this website) and just need to adjust the time somehow?

Comment: From what I understand, you already have a working script and you want to skin it like the apple-counter demo. For the time, you want to countdown to the next 10AM (it reset to 24h at 10AM). Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the animation technique used is really a simple background transition 
of this background :

http://cnanney-files.s3.amazonaws.com/journal/apple-counter/filmstrip.png

as explained here :

http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter/

He uses the `setTimer()` and changes the position 5 times in a second to achieve the animation result.
For your purpose, try to do something like that (changing the actual code used)

```
...
// SET TARGET DATE HERE
var currentTime = new Date();

currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate() + 1);

var month = currentTime.getMonth();
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var target = new Date(year, month, day, 10, 00, 00);
...
```

and then checking that the diff between the target day and now() is calculated correctly

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way they calculate the *target*, and also re-initialize everything when your reach that target, so that it re-starts the countdown.

A method that will initialze all vars of that script

```
function SetNextTarget(){
    now = new Date();
    // check if we are past todays time
    if (now.getHours() >= 10 && now.getMinutes() >= 00)
    {
        // set tomorrow time if we are passed todays time
        end = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+1, 10, 0,0);
    }
    else
    {
        //set today time if we have not reached it yet
        end = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 10, 0,0);
    }
    theDiff = end-now;
    theDiffString = getTimeString(theDiff);
}
```

and you need to call that right before the `initialDigitCheck()` method, and also call it once you reach 0 in the countdown (*inside the `doCount()` method*)

full demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zEAnJ/